# GameKit Match - invite friends between iOS5 and iOS6

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I'm trying to implement Game Center invites in a 2-person realtime game. Since invites are not supported in the simulator, I'm testing this on one device running iOS5 and a second one running iOS6 (this is done on purpose).

If I'm using the old-fashioned built-in `GKMatchmakerViewController` UI on either device to initiate the invite, it works fine both ways - when the iOS5 device initiates the invite as well as when the iOS6 device initiates it.

However, in iOS6 I want to use my own UI to select the player to invite, so I'm using `GKMatchRequest` to programmatically issue the invite, setting the `playersToInvite` attribute.

The problem is, the other (iOS5) device gets the push notification, launches the application, runs the `[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler`, shows the Game Center UI with the invite details, but even when the iOS6 device sends a `finishMatchmakingForMatch` request - the iOS5 device doesn't proceed any further. No other handler / delegate is called on the iOS5 machine, no `GKMatch` object is returned, and it continues to show the Game Center UI with both players marked as "Ready" and with a message saying "Waiting for [iOS6 player] to start the game". The only button on this UI is a Cancel button.

Here's the code snippet that sends the invitation on the iOS6 machine:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.playersToInvite = [NSArray arrayWithObject:playerID];
request.inviteMessage = message;
request.inviteeResponseHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKInviteeResponse response)
{
   if (response == GKInviteeResponseAccepted)
      [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] finishMatchmakingForMatch:self.match];
};
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error)
{
   ... [whatever]
}];
```

And here's the code snippet for the invite handler on the iOS5 machine:

```
[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite)
{
    if (acceptedInvite)
    {
        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
        [navController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
    });
    else if (playersToInvite)
    {
        ... [whatever]  
    }
}
```

The sequence is as follows:

- iOS6 sends a `findMatchForRequest` request with the iOS5 player id.
- A push notification is shown on the iOS5 machine.
- The application is launched on the iOS5 machine and the `inviteHandler` is called.
- The `GKMatchmakerViewController` is shown on the iOS5 machine with the invite details, and the iOS6 user has a spinning "Connecting" status.
- The `inviteeResponseHandler` on the iOS6 machine is called and sends a `finishMatchmakingForMatch` request.
- The status of the iOS6 user in the iOS5 Game Center screen changes from spinning "Connecting" to "Ready", and at this point both players are marked as "Ready".
- The iOS6 machine gets a `match: player: didChangeState:` callback, showing the iOS5 player as `GKPlayerStateConnected`, so as far as the iOS6 machine is concerned the match process is finished and the game can begin.
- Nothing whatsoever happens from now on on the iOS5 machine. It is stuck with "Waiting for [iOS6 user] to start the game" until it is cancelled by a timeout. It never receives any `GKMatch` object at any point, so it cannot start the game.

Since things work fine if I use the standard Game Center UI on the iOS6 machine rather than a programmable invite, it means that the standard UI must do something more to tell the other machine that the game has to start. However, I browsed through all the relevant Game Center objects and couldn't find anything else to send.

I should mention again that the reverse configuration (iOS5 initiating the invite using the standard UI) works fine on both machines.

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem.  One of the things I did to partially solve is to use programmatic for ios6 users, and viewController for ios5 users. I think you are doing that too but your inviteHandler code only seems to have viewController code.  Were you able to fully solve your issue?